# How to delete the gap

Tags: html, css, animation

I am doing an animation with CSS. The animation is a `div` moving from right to left without stop. The problem is that when the div arrive to the final, there is a huge white gap, so I have to wait too much for see again the div. How can I delete that gap?

I have one div container, that contains the `div1` that moves, and `div1` has another div with an iframe within it. I know that can be a little confusing, so, any suggest to change my code or delete the gap it will be helpful. This is my CSS code:

```css
#container {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 8600px;
  /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}
#div1 {
  float: right;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 8500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 90s;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  height: 1100px;
  width: 1400px;
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    right: -8000px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}
iframe {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1300px;
  /*iframes size*/
  border: none;
  /*MAKE ZOOM ON THE IFRAMES*/
  -ms-zoom: 1.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like that gap is caused by the body's `margin` of the content.

Comment: What do you mean? Because I did not use any margin property. Only the iframes are with zoom, but I don't think that would be the problem. Am I right?

Comment: The iframes, if you open them in the browser, on a separate window, they would be having margins right?

Comment: Ok, I've got it. The problem was at the keyframes move, when I use 50%, I don't  have to use it. Only from 0% to 100%.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the `@keyframes` configuration. I guess, the animation finishes off from `0%` to `50%` and nothing happens at the half of the time. So, from `50%` to `100%`, nothing happens, so please remove the `50%` declaration here:

```css
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    right: -8000px;
  }
  /*
  50% {
    right: 100%;
  }
  */
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```css
#container {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 8600px;
  /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}
#div1 {
  float: right;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 8500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 90s;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  height: 1100px;
  width: 1400px;
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    right: -8000px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}
iframe {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1300px;
  /*iframes size*/
  border: none;
  /*MAKE ZOOM ON THE IFRAMES*/
  -ms-zoom: 1.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <iframe src="url" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```